# Verify Overloaded Method Call

Tags: java, mockito

I am attempting to verify that a method was called a number of times using the Mockito `verify` functionality. The problem I am encountering however is that the method is overloaded so it claims that the method was not called. To Add a wrench into the mix, I also wish to capture what the argument was that was passed to this method. Here is what I have so far:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest() throws IOException {
    FlumeAppender mockAppender = Mockito.mock(FlumeAppender.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> arguments = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);

    // Load the message that should be sent to the class being tested
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testMessage.xml");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(in, writer, "UTF-8");
    String testMessage = writer.toString();

    // Send a message to the class being tested. This class will 
    // (hopefully) call the function I am listening to below
    eventSubscriber.handleMessage(testMessage);

    // Verify that the append method was called twice
    Mockito.verify(mockAppender, Mockito.times(2)).append(
            arguments.capture());

    // Do something with the arguments
}
```

Like I said, the function I am attempting to verify (append) is overloaded. Is it possible to specify which append function I am asking to verify while still capturing the arguments?

Comment: How does the `eventSubscriber` know about the `mockAppender`?

Comment: eventSubscriber has a setter for the appender. I have manually set it after creating the mockAppender.

Comment: Had a similar issue today - had an object declared as a field with the @Mock annotation, and only told the Mock to doCallRealMethod() for one of the two methods. Looked like mockito could not handle overloading, but it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I have discovered the solution to my problem was the result of a simple error. I will post the answer for reference.

When creating the ArgumentCaptor, specify the argument type you are expecting using generics. I had done this, but sadly I used the type from one of the other versions of the method that I was not expecting to be called. Simple mistake.

```
// This declaration
ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> arguments = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);

// Should have been:
ArgumentCaptor<Event> arguments = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
```

Once this is correct the verify function should work as expected, using the type from the ArgumentCaptor to determine which method to look at.

So close...